# How to define instance methods in mongoose.js subdocument array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

```
var ChildSchema = new Schema({
  createdAt : Date,
  name : String
});

var ParentSchema = new Schema({
  children : [ChildSchema]
});
```

With the above schema, I want to have some methods in `parent.children`, such as `parent.children.getLatest()` which will return the latest `child` being added to `parent.children` based on `createdAt`

I think I could only define instance methods on each `child` by `ChildSchema.methods.getName = function ...`

Answer (score 0):

To define instance or static methods for a subdocument is not mentioned in the current document.

However you can define instance or static methods for the features in the document, in this case, `ParentSchema`.